# How can I pass variables betweet two Subs in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I know how to pass the variables between two Subs when calling a sub running the action from within the Sub containing the variables set up, but I want to call the variable setup Sub from within the routine macro but can not get the correct place to declare the variables to get it to work.  I want to have the Variable set up separate to be called by other Subs. The code below does not work as the two subs

```
Sub X_Variables(s1, s2, s3, rng1, rng2, rng3)
'

' x - Defined Cell Names  - ANFlightText , AUFlightText , ABFlightText

Dim s1   As Worksheet
Dim s2   As Worksheet
Dim s3   As Worksheet
Dim rng1  As Range
Dim rng2  As Range
Dim rng3  As Range

Set s1 = Sheets("5_Angebot")        ' WorkSheet
Set s2 = Sheets("5_Auftragsb")      ' WorkSheet
Set s3 = Sheets("5_Abschluss")      ' WorkSheet
Set rng1 = s1.Range("B15")          ' End on cell
Set rng2 = s2.Range("B15")          ' End on cell
Set rng3 = s3.Range("B15")          ' End on cell

End Sub
```

Called by

```
Sub X_Offer_Hide_Flight_Text()
'
' ***** Hide Flight Text  *****

' x - Defined Cell Names  - ANFlightText , AUFlightText , ABFlightText
' x (s1, s2, s3, rng1, rng2, rng3)


'  ***** Set up veriables *****

Call X_Variables

' *****

' Hide rows
Application.ScreenUpdating = False  ' do not see screen updating

s1.Select
Range("ANFlightText").Select        ' x
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
rng1.Select

s2.Select
Range("AUFlightText").Select        ' x
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
rng2.Select

s3.Select
Range("ABFlightText").Select        ' x
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
rng3.Select

s1.Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True  ' see screen updating

End Sub
```

Comment: You cannot redeclare (`Dim`) the same vars you are passing in as parameters. Either declare them in **X_Offer_Hide_Flight_Text** and pass them in as parameters or declare them as public vars in the *Declarations* section of the module code sheet. If you are looking to tidy up your code, perhaps you need a class for the set of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare the variables as global, outside of the sub.

```
public s1   As Worksheet
public s2   As Worksheet
public s3   As Worksheet
public rng1  As Range
public rng2  As Range
public rng3  As Range

Sub X_Variables()
'

' x - Defined Cell Names  - ANFlightText , AUFlightText , ABFlightText

Set s1 = Sheets("5_Angebot")        ' WorkSheet
Set s2 = Sheets("5_Auftragsb")      ' WorkSheet
Set s3 = Sheets("5_Abschluss")      ' WorkSheet
Set rng1 = s1.Range("B15")          ' End on cell
Set rng2 = s2.Range("B15")          ' End on cell
Set rng3 = s3.Range("B15")          ' End on cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a module.  (In VBA: Insert -> Module)

Modules are similar in function to classes and it should work fine here.  In the module, you can set some properties:

```
Public CustomerID As Integer
```

for example.  Then in the sub, you can use dot notation to extract that info:

```
ID = ModuleName.CustomerID
```

You can then use the module everywhere in you excel file and even export it.  If you want to be able to initialize an array using information in the module, you can write a function to do that, and then pass in an array by reference (using the ByRef keyword)  Then when the module completes, you'll have a array full of the data you need.  I would recommend using arrays rather than naming multiple variables with a 1, 2, 3 as you do here.   Example:

In Module, AirlineInfo:

```
Sub Setup(ByRef s() As Worksheet, ByRef rng() As Range)

Set s(1) = Sheets("5_Angebot")        ' WorkSheet
Set s(2) = Sheets("5_Auftragsb")      ' WorkSheet
Set s(3) = Sheets("5_Abschluss")      ' WorkSheet
Set rng(1) = s(1).Range("B15")          ' End on cell
Set rng(2) = s(2).Range("B15")          ' End on cell
Set rng(3) = s(3).Range("B15")          ' End on cell
End Sub
```

Then from elsewhere in the file you can call that function in the module (like a method in the class)

```
Dim s(1 to 3)   As Worksheet
Dim rng(1 to 3)  As Range

ArilineInfo.Setup(s, rng)
```

As a quick fix, you might try just adding ByRef to your current setup, but you might need to use the module.